# How do you craft the new nether blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The nether now has awesome structures, built out of nether brick, fence and stair blocks. Is it possible to craft these or do I have to mine them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can craft the Nether Fences and Nether Stairs using Nether Brick in the same crafting recipe as regular fences (3 on the bottom row, 2 on the middle row and 1 on the top row). However if you're playing on a version older than 1.5, you can't craft Nether Brick, you must mine it, so for all intents and purposes, you pretty much have to mine all of them then.

Answer (score 5):

[Nether Bricks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Brick_%28item%29) can now be made by smelting [Netherrack](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Netherrack). These can then then be combined to make Nether Brick blocks.